# Executing Subst command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, subst

Would anybody help in executing Subst command in PowerShell; so that it reflects the virtual drive in Windows Explorer!

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I'm also not being able to use `subst` in my script.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Invoke-Expression "subst Z: C:\some\folder"
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Unfortunately, it does not show the virtual drive in Windows Explorer. It works within PowerShell console or PSIE.
Please suggest a way of creating the drive; which shows up in Explorer.

Comment: @RaabiAnony Press F5 to refresh the view in Explorer. Also check if Explorer is configured to hide empty drives (that's the default).

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Just to confirm, I created the same drive, Z for example; again in the Explorer; and it created as well as displayed it. 
Actually, I am trying it for a few days, using different ways; but without success.

Comment: @RaabiAnony All I can say is that it works just fine on my testbox. Directly as well as with `Invoke-Expression`, in the shell as well as in a script.

Comment: I am using Windows 8. Let me explore this aspect.